# Jenkins - can parsedVersion property be used in pipeline script?

Tags: maven, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins Maven project job thats builds a SNAPSHOT release and increments the POM version. Inside the Goals and options field I have:

> clean install build-helper:parse-version versions:set
>   -DnewVersion=${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion}-SNAPSHOT
>   versions:commit

This works as expected with no problems. But a separate Jenkins pipeline job fails when I attempt to esentially do the same thing using:

> sh mvn clean install build-helper:parse-version versions:set
>   -DnewVersion=${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion}-SNAPSHOT
>   versions:commit

The console output shows:

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: parsedVersion
>   for class: WorkflowScript     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:458)
>     at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:290)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onGetProperty(GroovyInterceptor.java:68)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:326)
>     at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:288)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:292)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:268)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:268)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:268)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:268)
>     at
>   com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
>     at
>   com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
>     at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:33)    at
>   ***cps.transform***(Native Method)    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
>     at
>   com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
>     at
>   com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor974.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
>     at
>   com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
>     at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)     at
>   com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)     at
>   com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
>     at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
>     at
>   jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Am I missing something?

Comment: In the pipeline code you have to quote `${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion` cause `$` is also a start for an identifier inside the pipeline code....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't get metalisticpain's solution to work but while troubleshooting I came across a GitHub groovy script with this approach:

> sh '/usr/local/maven/bin/mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set
>   -DnewVersion=\\\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\\\${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.\\\${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion}-SNAPSHOT
>   versions:commit '

Works perfectly now.

Comment: Why do we need \\\ ?

Answer (score 0):

<s>As alluded to by khmarbaise, you need to just enclose in **single** quotes.</s>

Specifically:

```
sh('mvn clean install build-helper:parse-version versions:set -DnewVersion=${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion}-SNAPSHOT versions:commit')
```

This will pass through without attempting to evaluate the ${var} as a Jenkins/Groovy variable. If you use double quotes, you will encounter the same error as this is a GString in groovy. http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GString.html

A different tact,
First read the pom into memory and extract the necessary data, then set it via mvn versions:set

```
def pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'
String major = pom.parsedVersion.majorVersion
String minor = pom.parsedVersion.majorVersion
String nextIncremental = pom.parsedVersion.majorVersion
sh("clean install build-helper:parse-version versions:set -DnewVersion=${major}.${minor}.${nextIncremental}-SNAPSHOT versions:commit")
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I originally used double quotes and saw the same exception as you predicted. However the sh command still fails with single quotes. The only error shown with single quotes is 'bad substitution'.

Comment: Amended, slightly more verbose but should work no dramas